# ¿Cómo guardar un archivo blob mediante url en HTML?

Tags: php, blob

En la tarde me mostraron la manera de como podria subir una imagen ubicada en mi disco, me la muestra con una URL como esta:

> blob:http://localhost/d1a568e5-7186-4a68-ae94-6c6430d5c90b

La cual es temporal y solo se puede acceder a esta imagen mientras permanezca en la página en donde la muestro, pero mi pregunta es, ¿cómo podría guardarla dentro de la carpeta de contiene mi index? Llevo rato investigando y no doy con una respuesta.

Esta función en [php](/questions/tagged/php) hace exactamente lo que quiero pero al parecer la imagen se guarda sin datos:

```
function save_img($image) {
    $img_file = file_get_contents($image);

    $image_path = parse_url($image);
    $img_path_parts = pathinfo($image_path['path']);

    $filename = $img_path_parts['filename'];
    $img_ext = $img_path_parts['extension'];

    $path = "Imagenes/";
    $filex = $path.$filename.
    ".".$img_ext;
    $fh = fopen($filex, 'w');
    fputs($fh, $img_file);
    fclose($fh);
    return filesize($filex);
}
```

Comment: De que motor de base de datos estamos hablando? Ese código que pones para más bien un ID que el contenido de un blob.

Comment: @Alexis, fijate en este link, tiene el código que necesitas. https://norfipc.com/inf/como-subir-fotos-imagenes-servidor-web.php